# How to explicitly start a transaction in the flow of a TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In our code base, we use `TransactionScope` extensively to manage our transactions. We have code that could look like this in one part of our codebase:

```
// options declared elsewhere
using var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

await _repository.DeleteAll(cancellationToken);

// do more stuff, that might trigger a call to SaveChangesAsync somewhere

transactionScope.Complete()
```

Then, in our repository implementation, we may have something that looks like this:

```
public async Task DeleteAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // This may not even be necessary
    if (_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        await _dbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("DELETE FROM ThatTable", cancellationToken);
}
```

The documentation of `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` states that no transaction is started by that method. This leads me to my question: what is the proper way to start a transaction and have it enlisted in the transaction scope so that the call to `Complete` will commit this transaction along with the other work we have EF do?

Comment: The proper way is to not execute raw SQL

Comment: Yeah, that's not feasible if you want to remove a couple thousands rows that contain large JSON content. The naive way would be to load them all in and remove them all from the set, so I don't agree with your assessment.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a third-party library to work efficiently with deleting and updating entities. [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/). My choice is linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: Looking at linq2db, it seems that you need to pass the connection string with the `Trusted_Connection=true` option. This is because the library needs to be able to create its own connection from the connection string, therefore can't do the bulk delete in the same transaction as the other work. In other words, it's useless to me.

Comment: Did you try if that works as is? I don't see why `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` would not enlist into existing transaction scope.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde did you try https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions it could help you!

Comment: @LeandroToloza yes, I realized this today while the team was discussing another issue, indeed it can do a bulk delete, but does it do it in a transaction? It merits further investigation.

Comment: Yeah @DaveVandenEynde check it on github you can execute the bulk operations as transactions, on the readme file, there is a BulkInfo apartment that explain how to implement it! if it solve your problem i'll post it as an answer!

Comment: @LeandroToloza I was just browsing the repo, cloned it to be able to navigate better because it wasn't very clear, but now it is: it takes a list of entities, and probably deletes them faster by bulk inserting the ids into a table, but it doesn't delete entities based on a LINQ query, for instance. Also, it just creates a query, then uses ExecuteSqlRawAsync, so it doesn't start a transaction either.

Comment: Moreover, the documentation states if you want a transaction, you should call BeginTransaction yourself, and that doesn't come close to what I need.

Comment: Could you answer Evk's question above? This should work as-is. Also, it's not clear why you need a transaction. All we see is one atomic SQL statement. It doesn't need a transaction.

Comment: @GertArnold no, that's not true. I need both the SaveChanges and the ExecuteSqlRaw to be part of the transaction.

Comment: Well, maybe, but it doesn't show in the code you present. But, again, is there a real problem, did you *experience* that the transaction is broken? The question is very unclear.

Comment: @GertArnold but yes, it should work as is. The only thing is, the documentation for ExecuteSqlRaw states that it does not _start_ a transaction. That may have led to some confusion.

Comment: @GertArnold the team will be testing it this week.

Comment: Also, whatever I said about the purpose of `Trusted_Connection` is simply not true. I confused it with `Persist Security Info`, which we needed for a POC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, your goal is to run both `DeleteAll` (which uses `ExecuteSqlRawAsync`) and potential following `SaveChangesAsync` in the same transaction. If so - your code already achieves that.

Yes, `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` does not start a separate transaction, but you do not need another transaction, you are already inside a transaction, because you are inside `TransactionScope`. `SqlClient` (or whatever other provider for EF you use) will notice there is abmient `Transaction.Current` when connection is opened and will start a transaction. Both `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` and `SaveChangesAsync` will run inside that transaction and complete or rollback together (I verified it to be sure).

The comment about "doesn't start transaction" is more for situations like:

```
ExecuteSqlRawAsync("delete from sometable where id = 1;delete from sometable where id = 2;");
```

Where you indeed might want to run your sql inside a transaction (assuming one doesn't already exists), and so docs warn you that it will not do that for you.

Comment: We tested it out today and indeed, that's what it does. I went through the git repos of both EF Core and Microsoft.Data.Sql, and couldn't find where it actually starts the transaction, or when it happens at all in the whole flow.  And yet, by making the second part fail we observed that the transaction was indeed rolled back.

Comment: If you want to know more about this, you can read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/distributed-transactions#automatically-enlisting-in-a-distributed-transaction. And if using sql server, this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/system-transactions-integration-with-sql-server

Comment: So, internally, it notices that Transaction.Current is not null (since you are inside transaction scope) and enlists into that transaction. Because sql server supports what is described as promotable transaction above - no distributed transaction happens in your case since it's not needed and the end result is just regular sql transaction being started when connection is opened.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach would be to do as follows (to start a transaction and stay within the transaction scope so that the call to complete will commit it):

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(...))
{
    ...
    scope.Complete();
}
```

The transaction would begin as soon as you go within the brackets.

Comment: You know what, you may be right. We're still investigating and I don't see immediately in the source where this happens, but it might be just as simple as this.